# login with facebook domain

Tags: facebook, authentication

I have a problem with facebook login using passport. I've got this:

```
//PASSPORT

passport.use(
  new FacebookStrategy(
{
  clientID: keys.id,
  clientSecret: keys.secret',
  callbackURL: '/auth/facebook/callback',
  proxy: true
},
async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
  const user = await User.findOrCreate({ facebookID: profile.id });
  if (user) done(null, user);
}
)
);


//AUTH ROUTES

module.exports = app => {
app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook'));

app.get(
'/auth/facebook/callback',
passport.authenticate('facebook'),
(req, res) => {
  res.redirect('/');
}
);
};
```

Im  trying to get it work on localhost:3000. In my app settings on facebook dev I have site url: localhost:3000 and appdomain to localhost. But.. IT doesnt work. When I go to (/auth/facebook) im getting a message (similar to this):

> Unable to load URL: The domain of this URL is not included in the
>   application domains...

Comment: up, still having this problem

Comment: Yes me too, did you get it to work?